# Preact/Typescript: Only allow a specific component as children

Tags: typescript, preact

Is it possible to only allow a specific component as children? Eg:

```js
function ListItem() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
    
function OrderedList(children: <ListItem>[] /* won't work */ ) {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You could probably check the component type in the parent when rendering? Not sure if this would work in preact: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729582/check-type-of-react-component

Comment: Seems like children can be any of those types, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55214477/1627271) for more details about it. Meanwhile, I believe [this gist](https://gist.github.com/coryhouse/f972ade3ce0ed2215a8211487ebdb751) is also trying to do the same as you.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not trying to actually filter out children of other types, just want Typescript not to compile. Also i'm on Preact, not React (if that was unclear).

Answer (score 2):

It is not the problem at Preact level. It is a problem with TypeScript itself in regards to how it deals with JSX/TSX. You cannot really enforce the children to be of specific type, since children could be anything - string/number/boolean/

However, all hope is not lost. You can specify that component should accept any component as `children` (one or many) prop, as long as it satisfies certain props using `VNode<T>` generic interface. For example:

```
import { VNode } from 'preact';

interface ChildProps {
  itemTitle: string;
}

function Child(props: ChildProps) {
  return (
    <div>Children</div>
  );
}

export interface ParentProps {
  children: VNode<ChildProps> | VNode<ChildProps>[];
}

function Parent(props: ParentProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child itemTitle='Child 1' />
      <Child itemTitle='Child 2' />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

The only catch here is that if you have some other component say `Child2` which accepts similar props as that of `Child1`, TypeScript will happily accept that.